# Как настроить gradle проект для java web

Tags: java, servlet, gradle

Доброго времени суток, начал изучать Java EE и хочу создать проект на gradle.
 Как настроить gradle, для работы с tomcat без web.xml то есть я хочу использовать 
`@WebServlet("/")` аннотацию, в maven это было так

`<configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>`
Постоянно жалуется на artifact.И если не в тягость напишите, пожалуйста, как создавать и настраивать такие проекты с 0, а точнее как вы это делали(делаете).
Работаю я в Intellij IDEA, создаю вот так [image: Скрин Создания проекта]
после этого только подключаю tomcat.

## UPDATE 1

При использовании GlassFush 4.1.1
все равно ошибка:

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
>       at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>       at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.logging.FileHandler.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
>       at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)

Понимаю что дело в артефакте, но не могу понять как настроить.

Answer (score 1):

Привет, я сам начинаю только работать в этом направление, но попробую помочь.
Maven и сервер приложений разные вещи. 
Используй сразу сервер приложений, например glassfish, в котором уже есть tomcat.
Если хочешь аннотациями помечать, то тебе нужно добавить аннотацию`@WebServlet (
name="название сервлета"
urlPatterns="/адрес сервлета"
)`

Можно также через web.xml, к примеру:

```
<servlet>
<display-name>Название Сервлета</display-name>
<servlet-class>servlets.TestServlet // путь до сервлета
</servlet>
```

Затем ему нужно указать маппинг

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Адрес сервлета</url-pattern>
```

Comment: К сожаление мне не помогло, проблема с запуском так и осталась

Comment: Тут проблема не в артефакте, а в glassfish, он пишет, что проблема с доступом glassfish, ты через ide запускаешь? 
И что пишет насчет артефакта? конкретнее? может библиотеки не всунул, может собираешь не так.

Comment: запускаю через ide, полный exeption добавил в вопрос, ипользую только javax.servlets которые добавляю в dependency в gradle

Comment: Запустил ide от имени администратора, сервер поднялся, но не видит проанатированные сервлеты, error 404 если заходить на страницу за которую должен отвечать сервлет

Comment: Ты как на него заходишь то?
У тебя путь примерно такой должен быть:
localhost:8080/Адрес_приложения/TestServlet

Comment: вы не совсем понимаете мою проблему, вся суть в том что если я создаю проект без gradle, все работает и путь localhost:8080/Адрес_приложения/TestServlet такой и все работает, но мне нужна помощь именно в настройке(подключении) gradle